# General Matrix computation in Python, TF-IDF

Tags: python, matrix, tf-idf

While generating TF-IDF module, I just faced this matrix-vector computation.

```
A % b = C

[[1,2], [3,4]] % [1/2, 1/3] = [[1/2, 2/3], [3/2, 4/3]]
```

Here `A` is a matrix of `Document x Words` where `A_ij` is a Term-Frequency count of word `i` in document `j`. And `b` vector is pre-calculated IDF value for each words, for instance `b_j` is 1/7 if word `j` is used among 7 different documents.

How does the people call this column-wise multiplication?
And are there any existing library support this operation? (Python)

- Because of the large size & sparsity, I have been using `csr_matrix` in `scipy` to save matrix.
- I tried to change them to np.array and execute `A*b` operations, however it didn't finish in few minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/) for it.**

It is *element-wise multiplication*:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
b = np.array([1/2, 1/3])
print(A * b)
```

output:

```
[[ 0.5         0.66666667]
 [ 1.5         1.33333333]]
```

**In case of csr_matrix**:

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
x1 = csr_matrix([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
x2 = csr_matrix([1/2, 1/3])
print(x1.multiply(x2).todense())
```

output:

```
[[ 0.5         0.66666667]
 [ 1.5         1.33333333]]
```

Comment: What if I have been using scipy matrices for A and b?